# php sessions saved in ramdisk

Tags: php, apache, session, centos, ramdisk

I'm trying to save my php session on ramdisk. I have a permission problem but i can't see what  where it's the problem.

1. I have the ramdisk:

   `/dev/ram0 407M   2.4M   404M   1% /var/lib/php/session/ramd`
2. I have the permissions:

   `drwxrwx---. 3 root   apache 1024 Mar 24 01:53 ramd`
3. My error:

   `Warning: session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session/ramd/sess_b0ko6hl3p6ojj2ot3qfqvm9km1, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3 Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/ramd/sess_b0ko6hl3p6ojj2ot3qfqvm9km1, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session/ramd) in Unknown on line 0`
4. In php.ini, session.save_path variable it's set to `"/var/lib/php/session"`
5. In my script i set session.save_path to `"var/lib/php/session/ramd"`

If i umont the ramdisk that i created, i can save my sessions in /rand folder. It i mount.. i can't. I tried also chmod root:root / apache:apache with chmod 0777 1777. now it's 0770.

I using: CentOS 6.4, PHP 5.3.3, Apache/2.2.15

Can anybody help me with this problem??

LE:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps aux | grep apache
apache    2355  0.0  0.4 394868  7840 ?        S    01:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2356  0.0  0.4 394876  7844 ?        S    01:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2357  0.0  0.4 394876  7824 ?        S    01:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2358  0.0  0.4 394876  7816 ?        S    01:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2360  0.0  0.4 394876  7900 ?        S    01:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2361  0.0  0.4 394876  7800 ?        S    01:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2362  0.0  0.4 394876  7844 ?        S    01:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2363  0.0  0.4 394868  7716 ?        S    01:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      3119  0.0  0.0 103248   868 pts/0    S+   02:52   0:00 grep apache

[root@localhost ~]# ps aux | grep php
root      3132  0.0  0.0 103244   868 pts/0    S+   02:54   0:00 grep php
```

Comment: Did you try what you wrote down or did you actually do: `chown -R root:root /var/lib/php/session/ramd` and `chmod -R 0777 /var/lib/php/session/ramd`?

Comment: Yes, i tryied to write a short version :). `chown -R root:root /var/lib/php/session/ramd chmod -R 0777 /var/lib/php/session/ramd` and `chown -R apache:apache /var/lib/php/session/ramd chmod -R 0777 /var/lib/php/session/ramd`

Comment: does PHP run as cgi process or as an apache module? Can you show the output of `ps aux` command , only apache/php processes?

Comment: Apache module. I will edit my question for ps aux.

Comment: While using CentOS for a short while, I learned that disabling SELinux was answer to many permission problems

Comment: what if `chown apache:apache /var/lib/php/session/ramd` as root? and try then?

Comment: it works with `chown apache:apache` BUT only with SELinux disabled ... I don't think disabling SELinux it's a solution .. especially for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following to see if SELinux is in enforcing mode:

```
# sestatus
```

If so, you may want to try disabling SELinux by running the following as root (or with sudo):

```
# setenforce 0
```

This will make SELinux stop enforcing any policies. If this solves the issue, you will have to either leave SELinux off or augment the policy to allow this new path to work out correctly. If it does get to that point, reference https://serverfault.com/a/323528/165777 for some information on how to perform that step!

Also, if that didn't make an impact and/or you want to re-enable SELinux, execute:

```
# setenforce 1
```